# django summernote create custom buttons

Tags: django, summernote

I'd like to add a custom button similar to this one:

```
$('#makeSnote').click(function(event) {
 var highlight = window.getSelection(),  
   spn = document.createElement('span'),
   range = highlight.getRangeAt(0)

   spn.innerHTML = highlight;
   spn.className = 'snote';  
   spn.style.color = 'blue';

   range.deleteContents();
   range.insertNode(spn);
});
```

JS Fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/ypweuw1L/

I'm not sure how would I go about adding this into my Django app? I don't see anything in the django-summernote docs.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about django-summernote well. But you can create custom button and use it on toolbar with options.

for more details...
http://summernote.org/deep-dive/#custom-button